# Popup ToolTip for Rectangular Region Drawn in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a rectangular region that I'm filling using JavaScript in HTML5, and I need to add a ToolTip pop-up to display text when the user touches/clicks on it in a hand-held or hovers over it in a browser.  I've looked at the examples already on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to address this specific situation, where the area that is to contain the hover point are drawn using JavaScript.

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a simple tool-tip class/object that will handle states, position etc.

## Example

- This will create an instance of the class
- When hovering or clicking the box, it will show
- After timeout it will hide the tool-tip

One considerations that is not implemented: If a second instance is shown, the previous is not hidden. Create a public method that will clear the timeout and hide it when this happens for the other instances (store them in an array and iterate it to call the hide method).

In any case, this should be a solid basis to build upon in any way you prefer.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    region = {x: 50, y: 50, w: 100, h: 100};

ctx.fillStyle = "#79f";
ctx.fillRect(region.x, region.y, region.w, region.h);

// create a tool-tip instance:
var t1 = new ToolTip(canvas, region, "This is a tool-tip", 150, 3000);

// The Tool-Tip instance:
function ToolTip(canvas, region, text, width, timeout) {

  var me = this,                                // self-reference for event handlers
      div = document.createElement("div"),      // the tool-tip div
      parent = canvas.parentNode,               // parent node for canvas
      visible = false;                          // current status
  
  // set some initial styles, can be replaced by class-name etc.
  div.style.cssText = "position:fixed;padding:7px;background:gold;pointer-events:none;width:" + width + "px";
  div.innerHTML = text;
  
  // show the tool-tip
  this.show = function(pos) {
    if (!visible) {                             // ignore if already shown (or reset time)
      visible = true;                           // lock so it's only shown once
      setDivPos(pos);                           // set position
      parent.appendChild(div);                  // add to parent of canvas
      setTimeout(hide, timeout);                // timeout for hide
    }
  }
  
  // hide the tool-tip
  function hide() {
    visible = false;                            // hide it after timeout
    parent.removeChild(div);                    // remove from DOM
  }

  // check mouse position, add limits as wanted... just for example:
  function check(e) {
    var pos = getPos(e),
        posAbs = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};  // div is fixed, so use clientX/Y
    if (!visible &&
        pos.x >= region.x && pos.x < region.x + region.w &&
        pos.y >= region.y && pos.y < region.y + region.h) {
      me.show(posAbs);                          // show tool-tip at this pos
    }
    else setDivPos(posAbs);                     // otherwise, update position
  }
  
  // get mouse position relative to canvas
  function getPos(e) {
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top}
  }
  
  // update and adjust div position if needed (anchor to a different corner etc.)
  function setDivPos(pos) {
    if (visible){
      if (pos.x < 0) pos.x = 0;
      if (pos.y < 0) pos.y = 0;
      // other bound checks here
      div.style.left = pos.x + "px";
      div.style.top = pos.y + "px";
    }
  }
  
  // we need to use shared event handlers:
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", check);
  canvas.addEventListener("click", check);
  
}
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid blue;background:#eee}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=300></canvas>
```