# Tooltip on image at particular position

Tags: wordpress, tooltip

I have an image in wordpress which contains four info icons on that image. When mouse hover on each info icon show tooltip.
Info icons are part of that image. So, is it possible to show tooltip on image when mouse hovers on particular position?

Comment: current tooltip uses "title" or some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using canvas, you can add event listeners to detect mouse movement and get mouse positions. Then test if the mouse is over one of your hot-spots where you want the tooltip to display.

Here's a similar question and answer. Your question isn't specific to what you're trying to accomplish, but this might help you on your way. If not, provide more information on your question.

[Displaying tooltips on mouse hover on shapes/position(coordinates) on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795139/displaying-tooltips-on-mouse-hover-on-shapes-positioncoordinates-on-canvas)

There are other useful links on that page as well.