# To add Tooltip dynamically for moving shapes on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tooltip

Here i'm working on drawing shapes in HTML canvas and moving them by setting setInterval function. But I need to add tooltip for each shape dynamically. Can't find an exact solution. Please help out. Please check out my [Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/npk0yLLh/2/)

```
function Shapes(x, y, w, color, shape) 
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.color = color;

    this.anim = function() 
    {
        if (this.x < context.canvas.width) {
            if(shape=="square"){
            this.x += 5;
            context.fillStyle = this.color;
            context.strokeStyle = "red";
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.w);
            context.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.w);
            }else if(shape=="triangle"){

                        this.x += 1;
                        context.beginPath();
                        context.moveTo(this.x, this.x-20);
                    context.lineTo(this.x+60, this.x);
                    context.lineTo(this.x+25, this.x+50);
                        context.closePath();
                        context.fillStyle = "blue";
                        context.fill();
                    }else if(shape=="circle"){
                            this.x += 1;
                            context.beginPath();
                            context.arc(this.x, this.y, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                            context.fillStyle = "green";
                            context.fill();
                            context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
                            context.stroke();
                    }
            if(shape=="rectangle"){
                            this.x += 1;
                    context.fillStyle = "#ff6600";
                    context.strokeStyle = "blue";
                    context.lineWidth = 3;
                    context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w+30,this.w);
                    context.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.w+30,this.w);
            }
        }
        else this.x=-this.w;
    }
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var max=200, min=0;

    var shapes =["square", "circle", "triangle", "rectangle"]

    var objects =[];

    for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
            var rectY = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            var rect1 = new Shapes(0, rectY, 40, "blue", shapes[i]);
            //var rect2 = new Shapes(0, 100, 40, "blue");
            objects.push(rect1);
        }

    setInterval(function(){
        blank();
        for(rect in objects){
            objects[rect].anim();
        }
    }, 30);
}

function blank() {
    context.fillStyle = "#ebebe0";
    context.fillRect(0,0,context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
}


init()
```

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29490892/1693593

Comment: Ditto, @K3N's tooltip answer is a great place to start. Tooltips tend to float out of the canvas area and using a separate div element allows the tooltip to float.

Comment: @K3N : I have integrated the code for tooltip from your answer but the tooltip is not displayed on the exact position and when the shape moves, the tooltip is not moving along with it, please check out my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/8w2z3a4f/1/)

Comment: @K3N - please help out. please check out my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/8w2z3a4f/1/